# PyPi package app runs instead of cloned repo with runserver command

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

For the repo here:
https://github.com/nyck33/eco_gamechanger/blob/master/cnf/templates/index.html.
What is weird is that views.py shows:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'], endpoint='cnf.index')
def index():
    q = request.args.get('q')
    foods = CNFFoodName.objects.filter(description__icontains=q) if q else []
    return render_template('index.html', foods=foods, q=q)
```

But index.html looks different:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container pt-4">
  <div class="row py-4">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h1>Canadian Nutrient File Food Search</h1>
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <form method='GET'>
        <input class="form-control" name="q" value="{{ q|default('', True) }}" />
      </form>
    </div>
    {% if foods %}
    <div class="col">
      <ul>
        {% for food in foods %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('cnf.show', food_id=food.id) }}">{{ food.description }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried just inserting a simple

hello

near the top which does not appear.
And actually it looks like this:
[image: show.html's actual rendering]

I can't find "Food Standards" anywhere in any template.
layout.html looks like this:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>CNF</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="{{ request.url_rule.endpoint }}" style="font-family: Muli">

  <header>
      {% include nav.html %}
  </header>

    {% block content %}
    <div>Hello World</div>
    {% endblock %}


    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/63a7e983e5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Also why is it that the heading:

```
<h1>Canadian Nutrient File Food Search</h1>
```

in `index.html` does not show up anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a grave error.  On the repo I cloned there are two options.  One is to install the PyPi package via `pip install canadian-nutrient-file` which I did IN THE SAME CONDA ENV I was using for the cloned repo version of the app.  Thus whenever I did `bin/cnf runserver` it would run the PyPi package app instead of the cloned repo so of course changes to the template would not be reflected.
The command to run the PyPi package is completely different so it did not strike me until I went back into the PyPi package and saw that its `index.html` does show "Food Standards" as the `<h1>` element.

```
CNF_MONGO_DB=mycnf cnf runserver
```

So I ran `pip uninstall -y canadian-nutrient-file` and now I can update templates normally.
Lesson learned is I'm guessing that a PyPi package has precedence over a cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

See `{% extends 'layout.html' %}`?  That is the wrapper for the template.  Look there.  `index.html` extends that.

Comment: I don't see "Food Standards" anywhere on layout.html.  Is it being injected from the model or CSVs?

Comment: Actually I've updated to note the fact that even the `<h1>` heading in `index.html` does not appear anywhere.